# Como remover mensagens de certificado do WebBrowser?

Tags: winforms, vb.net, navegador-de-internet

Como removo aquelas mensagens irritantes mostrando que o certificado da página não é válido ou é inseguro do componente `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`? Ja tentei diversas maneiras e não encontrei uma alternativa...

Uma das alternativas foi definir essa propriedade:

```
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

porém não adiantou, a outra foi baixar um componente chamado "GeckoFX" (o navegador do Mozilla) mas ele não tem suporte algum para HTML5...

Comment: Mostre as `diversas maneiras`, assim você evita respostas com o que já tentou e não funcionou ;)

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentar chamar isso, antes de abrir o `webbrowser`

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
    delegate
    { return true; }
);
```

Retirado [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301127/how-to-ignore-a-certificate-error-with-c-sharp-2-0-webclient-without-the-certi) do **SOen**

Aliás, é recomendável que tu entendas o impacto de ignorar essas mensagens.

**EDIT:**
Acabei deixando a resposta na linguagem original. Não programo `VB.Net` mas creio que isso seja o equivalente.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function() True)
```

Comment: Mas colocar isso aonde? No WebBrowser1.Load?

Comment: Conseguiste? @CypherPotato

Comment: Não, @Jeferson Bueno, pois não sei onde coloco esse Statement...

Comment: Ah, coloca no abrir da tela. Pensei que tinha conseguido porque marcou a resposta como correta.

Comment: Marquei como correta por que faz sentido e é a única resposta que tem